# Python: error when doing text classification task

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

the error occurred when I did the text classification task with convolutional neural network.

the network input is `tfidf(dim=2196)`, the output is `[0, 1]` or `[1, 0]`.

I think the reason is some tensor, but I can't tell which one.
Please take some minutes to look it. Thank you.

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a
>   tensor with 140544 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple
>   of 281088

```
class TextCNN(object):
    def __init__(self):

        # Placeholders for input, output and dropout
        self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2196], name="input_x")
        self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name="input_y")
        self.dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")

        conv_input = tf.reshape(self.input_x, [-1, 2196, 128, 1])

        # Keeping track of l2 regularization loss (optional)
        l2_loss = tf.constant(0.0)

        # Create a convolution + maxpool layer for each filter size
        pooled_outputs = []
        filter_sizes = [3, 4, 5]
        for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):
            with tf.name_scope("conv_maxpool_%s" % filter_size):
                # Convolution Layer
                filter_shape = [filter_size, 64, 1, 128]
                W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
                b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[128]), name="b")
                conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                    conv_input,
                    W,
                    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                    padding="SAME",
                    name="conv")
                # Apply nonlinearity
                h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu")
                # Maxpooling over the outputs
                pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                    h,
                    ksize=[1, 2196-128+1, 1, 1],
                    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                    padding='SAME',
                    name="pool")
                pooled_outputs.append(pooled)

        # Combine all the pooled features
        num_filters_total = 128 * len(filter_sizes)
        self.h_pool = tf.concat(pooled_outputs, 3)
        self.h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(self.h_pool, [-1, num_filters_total])

        # Add dropout
        with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
            self.h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat, 0.5)

        # Final (unnormalized) scores and predictions
        with tf.name_scope("output"):
            W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([num_filters_total, 2], -1.0, 1.0),
                            name="W")

            # the above error still occurred if the following W is used.
            # W = tf.get_variable(
            #     "W",
            #     shape=[num_filters_total, 2],
            #     initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[2]), name="b")
            l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W)
            l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(b)
            self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.h_drop, W, b, name="scores")
            self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")

        # CalculateMean cross-entropy loss
        with tf.name_scope("loss"):
            losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.scores, labels=self.input_y)
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses) + 0.0 * l2_loss

        # Accuracy
        with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
            correct_predictions = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
            self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
```

the following is the main function

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
      allow_soft_placement=FLAGS.allow_soft_placement,
      log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    with sess.as_default():
        cnn = TextCNN()
        # Define Training procedure
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
        grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
        train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)

        # Initialize all variables
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        def train_step(x_batch, y_batch):
            """
            A single training step
            """
            feed_dict = {
              cnn.input_x: x_batch,
              cnn.input_y: y_batch,
              cnn.dropout_keep_prob: 0.5
            }
            _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
                [train_op, global_step, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
                feed_dict)

        def dev_step(x_batch, y_batch):
            """
            Evaluates model on a dev set
            """
            feed_dict = {
              cnn.input_x: x_batch,
              cnn.input_y: y_batch,
              cnn.dropout_keep_prob: 1.0
            }
            accuracy = sess.run(cnn.accuracy, feed_dict)
            return accuracy

        def batch_iter(data, batch_size, num_epochs, shuffle=True):
            """
            Generates a batch iterator for a dataset.
            """
            data = np.array(data)
            data_size = len(data)
            num_batches_per_epoch = int((len(data) - 1) / batch_size) + 1
            for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                # Shuffle the data at each epoch
                if shuffle:
                    shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(data_size))
                    shuffled_data = data[shuffle_indices]
                else:
                    shuffled_data = data
                for batch_num in range(num_batches_per_epoch):
                    start_index = batch_num * batch_size
                    end_index = min((batch_num + 1) * batch_size, data_size)
                    yield shuffled_data[start_index:end_index]

        # Generate batches
        batches = batch_iter(
            list(zip(train_data, train_label)), 64, 5000)
        # Training loop. For each batch...

        for batch in batches:
            x_batch, y_batch = zip(*batch)
            train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
            current_step = tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should have a read of the documentation on how to ask a question as it may provide some useful advice on how to layout your question in a way that provokes more responses.

Comment: Add full error message into your question, please. And try to define line in which error was acquired.

And better try to create more specific test code with error.